# SQL Pivot Table with Subtraction

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using SQL and I have three columns of **user_id, user_action, and timestamp** that apply timestamps to five different types of user actions numbered 1 through 5.

I have several thousand user_ids and actions over a period of several years. [Example of Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgZGI.png)

1. First, I need to create a pivot table that has the timestamps from
   only two of the user_actions, grouped by user_id, and then create a
   brand new column that subtracts the time difference - call this
   column **time_difference**.

The code that was provided by Caius Jard in the comments works for this part.

2. Now, I need to add another column of week number (TIMESTAMP is in DATETIME2 format so I need to incorporate

`DATEPART(week, timestamp) as week` into this code and use it to create a two week moving average based on the week number and time_difference.

Comment: You may get a bit of backlash for posting screenshots of data - the guys here like to be able to take example data and whack it into something like db-fiddle.com to quick check queries they write and it can't be done with a screenshot. Bonus points for providing us with a pre-made fiddle (if using that site I mentioned, choose share, not collaborate) for future questions :)

Comment: I'll check out db-fiddle, thanks! still new to all of this

Comment: There are a few sql fiddle sites, with siffering sb support. The most comprehensive is probably dbfiddle.uk but do have a google for others

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a complete answer to the entire question. Here's a stub for step 1:

```
SELECT 
  user, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN action = 2 THEN action END) as action2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN action = 5 THEN action END) as action5,
  DATEDIFF(
    MAX(CASE WHEN action = 2 THEN action END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN action = 5 THEN action END) 
  ) as days_between
FROM t
WHERE action in (2,5)
GROUP BY user
```

Though this doesn't calculate your minus column-I wasn't entirely sure what data type timestamp is and whether any direct math was possible, or if it's a string that needs converting. If you can add this detail to your q it will help (or leave a comment)

I wasn't easily able to make sense of your step 2, please enhance your q by providing expected results

Comment: I got the next part by using a DATEDIFF()  DATEDIFF(second, MAX(CASE WHEN action = '2' THEN timestamp END), 
  MAX(CASE WHEN action = '5' THEN timestamp END)) as timediff which gets me the time difference in seconds. Now I only need to create the average_timediff by 2 week periods

Comment: Just a quick one; are you sure this is MySQL? That looks more like the datediff form that sql server uses but you've tagged mysql

Comment: Still not sure how you mean "in two week periods" as the data you posted doesn't contain any date info, so it's hard to tell how this data cycles around on different days

Comment: I updated the post. Still figuring this all out. I can get the week number from the timestamp. So I want to then take what you've done which works to create the two event times and timediff, than createa a fourth column showing the week number form the timestamp and do a moving average based on the timediff and weeks